# Why does the IP location differ if I visit Wikipedia on Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: ip, google-chrome-extensions, domain, firefox-extensions

I have the [IP Country Domain Flag](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ip-domain-country-flag/mlpapfcfoakknnhkfpencomejbcecdfp?hl=en) addon installed on Chrome and the [Flagfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flagfox/) addon installed on Firefox. Both are meant to report where the IP address of a domain name is hosted.

I understand that a single domain may have more than one IP address. But when I go to Wikipedia on Chrome, IP Country Domain Flag says that the server is located in the Netherlands, whereas if I visit Wikipedia on Firefox, it reports the server being in the US.

Why does this happen when I am using different browsers?

[image: See screenshot]

By the way, I am located in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Most large websites will use something called load balancing. Many servers will be behind Wikipedia. Each time you connect you will be sent to one of the servers who either caches a copy of the website to display, or has the live page. Which you get doesn't really matter for this question.

How the server is decided depends on how Wikipedia have set up their system.

- it may have a list of servers and say to each server in turn "Your up next, serve the next customer."
- It may say "American customer, American server respond" and if they are all busy, it may have a second rule saying "OK, America's busy, Some one else get that"

What is important is that each time you request the website, you may get a response from the same server or a completely different one. [198.35.26.96](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=198.35.26.96) does belong to Wikipedia in America and [91.198.174.192](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=91.198.174.192) does belong to them in the Netherlands.

Comment: No, this happens every time I visit Wikipedia in either Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Try pressing ctrl+F5 and see what happens, that will force a complete resend of the website. Just pressing F5 will ask the server to refresh what you have. Also, if you open up cmd and type netstat it will show your open connections. You should see your connection established in there to those wikipedia servers. Notice how the connections remain established even after the page is loaded. The server is still talking to you. you can use netstat -f to easily see the hostname

Answer (score -1):

It should not happened generally . Chrome and firefox are just clients. It may happened in your case because may there are 2 different servers nearby to each other  so the algorithm that returns nearby server is getting different result each time